# Is there a way to efficiently iterate over 'nested' combinations in Python?

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

I am unsure how to define the problem I wish to solve, but from a combinations of numbers, e.g.:

(4, 3, 2)

I wish to make an iterator that goes over all 'nested' combinations of these numbers. What I mean by this is that it iterates over:

(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), ...

(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (1, 3, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), ...

...

(4, 0, 0), (4, 1, 0), (4, 2, 0), (4, 3, 0), (4, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), ...

Preferably it could also be constrained by a maximum sum capacity during the generation of combinations (i.e. sum(combination) < capacity).

I have created a recursive algorithm that generates these combinations, but it is very slow and hope there is a more efficient method.

```py
import numpy as np 

def combinations(current, c, c_set):
    c_rec = c.copy()
    if(current == 0):
        while(c_rec[current] + 1 <= numbers[current] and c_rec[current] + 1 < capacity):
            c_rec[current] += 1
            c_set.append(c_rec.copy())

    while(c_rec[current] + 1 <= numbers[current] and c_rec[current] + 1 < capacity):
        c_rec[current] += 1
        combinations(current - 1, c_rec, c_set)
        c_set.append(c_rec)

numbers = (4,3,2)
n = len(numbers)
capacity = 7
c_init = np.zeros(n)
c_set = [c_init]            
combinations(n - 1, c_init, c_set)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In what sense are these combinations "nested"? Are you referring to the order that the combinations are generated? Is that particular order required? Please describe that order--your example does not make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this

```
from itertools import product

li = [4, 3, 2]

#Create a list of ranges
res = [range(item+1) for item in li]
#[range(0, 5), range(0, 4), range(0, 3)]

#Calculate cartesian product between elements of each list
prod = product(*res)

#Iterate over the elements
for item in prod:
    print(item)
```

The output will be

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
...
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
...
(2, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 0, 2)
(2, 1, 0)
(2, 1, 1)
.....
(3, 0, 0)
(3, 0, 1)
(3, 0, 2)
(3, 1, 0)
(3, 1, 1)
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not have fully understood your question, but wouldn't a simple nested for-loop structure solve your problem?

```
for x in range(4):
    for y in range(3):
        for z in range(2):
            print((x, y, z))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
This is a lot more simple! But I am looking for a generalized method that works for a vector of numbers of any length n (which would require n for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
start = (4, 3, 2)
def groups(d):
  yield d
  for i, [a, b] in enumerate(zip(d, start)):
    if a < b:
      yield from groups(tuple([*d[:i], d[i]+1, *d[i+1:]]))

result = set(groups((0, 0, 0)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 3, 0), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (4, 0, 0), (4, 0, 1), (4, 0, 2), (4, 1, 0), (4, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 2, 0), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), (4, 3, 0), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2)]
```